# Simple discrete wavelet transform for audio file source code in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am looking for simple discrete wavelet transform source code for audio file in matlab.
Can anyone tell me where can i find it?

Answer (score 1):

Discrete wavelet transform can be applied to any signal, so you can use `wavedec` or `dwt` function from image processing toolbox:

```
wname = 'haar'
[y Fs] = wavread('filename.wav');
[C L] = wavedec(y, 1, wname);
wavplay(C(1:L(1)),Fs/2)
```

You will hear your audio sample low-pass filtrated and downsampled